# Best method to play hi-res frame animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to play 6 sec hi-res video animation in the background of my activity views. On my device thats 1080x1080. The video has to have a transparent background. I did some research on AnimationDrawable and people say its a pain in the a... (OutOfMemory Exceptions,...)

I want to be able to loop the video and change the speed. The framerate should be at least 20fps.

How would you do it?

Comment: Not sure if Android supports video formats with alpha channel. I guess some trickery using OpenGL ES 2.0 may be done to achieve that, but I guess the quality and frame rate may suffer here because you'd have to decode the video and transfer it into texture memory (with all the size and speed constraints here). Alternatively it's a sequence of PNG images... but 6 seconds of them decoded in RAM... that's a lot. 1 bitmap would be 4MB in your case. and heap for an Android app is scarce. You could scale down the images and/or shorten the duration.

Answer (score 2):

I'd encode the video as a .mp4 (AVC), and decode it with [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) onto a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html), then render the texture with OpenGL ES.  What you render onto depends on what else your app is doing; either a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) or a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

You said the video is in the background, but also that it must have a transparent background, which suggests that it's somewhat in the foreground.  Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.  The video won't have an alpha channel, but you can use a fragment shader to set the alpha (either globally or according to the video pixel values).

You can find examples of video playback in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) (with looping and speed control).  The "texture from camera" activity is probably also relevant, as it illustrates rendering through a SurfaceTexture (though it's using live video from the camera rather than a recorded file).  The camera filter demo shows some [simple fragment shaders](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/Texture2dProgram.java#L67).